# JQuery.post Failed to execute 'postMessage'

Tags: javascript, jquery, .post

I have a simple $.post() that I want to execute

```
function(formData) {

var path = reg ? "login" : "regester";
formData.bundle_id = window.bundleId;
app.error = false;
app.unknown = false;
$.post(("/kanban/"+path+"/submit"),{"form":formData},function(data){
    if(data.success){
        window.location.href=data.redir;
    }
    else if(data.user) {
        window.location.href="/kanban";
    }
    else {
        app.error = true;
    }
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    app.unkown = true;
});
}
```

The app is defined by

```
const app = new Vue({...});
```

Currently, when the function is called I get the error

```
jquery.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.
at add (jquery.js:8463)
at buildParams (jquery.js:8450)
at buildParams (jquery.js:8444)
at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:8483)
at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9073)
at Function.jQuery.(/kanban/anonymous function) [as post] (https://127.0.0.1/kanban/js/jquery.js:9355:17)
at submitForm (register?bundle_id=-1:84)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this. It may be a simple syntax error but I can't find one.

I call my js method from here

```
<form action="javascript:submitForm(this)">
......
</form>
```

I'm running on Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 With jquery-3.3.1
I also have vue.js and alertify.js loaded on this page.

Is there a syntax problem I'm missing? Or is there a possible overlap.

Comment: where is your code running? in a worker by chance?

Comment: What is formData? If that is from a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object you have to use more `$.ajax` options to prevent processing it

Comment: My code is called from a button on a <form> @DanielA.White . and is not wrapped in any other js. just put inside a <script> tag

Comment: @charlietfl I eited the post for more clarity

Comment: was your version of jquery hacked at all?

Comment: You may want to consider using jQuery to bind to the `submit` event of the form rather than defining it inline. I don't know anything about Vue so if that's rewriting the HTML or JavaScript is some way that might be the cause.

Comment: No @DanielA.White Im pulling it directly from code.jquery.com But I think that my submitForm(this) may be my problem. Im trying to pass the data from the form into my js. but its adding much more then that. thats where my error is coming from. I got the Idea from charlietfl

Comment: It's probably the way you are trying to add params to `formData` look at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)
basically you do `formData.append('field', value)` - you may also need to add the request header 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' to your post call if you are going to use FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a form element to `$.post` as data and that can't be serialized.

Try changing to

```
var data = $(formData).serialize()
$.post("/kanban/"+path+"/submit", data, function(data){..
```

Now server will receive the data exactly the same way it would if the form was submitted using default browser process

Would also consider changing name of `formData` to `form` to minimize confusion

Comment: Thanks! the only thing I would like to add is that I had to change  <form  action="javascript:submitForm(this)"> To  <form name="regForm" action="javascript:submitForm(regForm)"> Because I was passing the whole window. But I got that from your comment on the post